# Unable to get while loop working (crashes page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I know I'm definitely doing something wrong. I'm new to Javascript and jQuery so it is probably something quite obvious, so please excuse my ignorance, I'm trying my best.

I made a basic maze complete with Start, finish, and walls to mess you up. When It's all completed, the walls will be made invisible to increase difficulty. The maze works as intended in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V2wxT/2/

**WORKING:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.start').click(function() {
        var x = 1;


    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $('body').css( "background-color", "yellow");
        x=x+1;
        alert("You hit a wall!");
    })
    $('#myTable tr td.finish').on('mouseenter',function(){
         x=x+1;
        alert("You did it!");
    })
    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $('body').css( "background-color", "white");
    })
  });
});
```

The issue I have with that is, once you hit a wall I want you to have to hit start again so that it cancels the "Finish" alert, and the alerts when you hit the walls.

What I tried to do was add a while loop to say "As long as x=1, allow the alerts from finish, and wall hits to occur" Once you hit a wall, or finish the maze, it adds +1 x.

**MY NON WORKING WHILE LOOP:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.start').click(function() {
    var x = 1;

    while(x=1){

    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $('body').css( "background-color", "yellow");
        x=x+1;
        alert("You hit a wall!");
    })
    $('#myTable tr td.finish').on('mouseenter',function(){
         x=x+1;
        alert("You did it!");
    })
    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $('body').css( "background-color", "white");
    })

    } 

   });
});
```

And here is the JSFiddle with that while loop that seems to crash the page: http://jsfiddle.net/V2wxT/3/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially since I think it's something simple I'm over looking.

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave events don't stop unless you tell it to, so don't see why its neccesary to use the while, try not using the while, as it attempts to bind the mouseenter and mouseleave events a lot of times and freezes program

Comment: @juvian Well, how can I tell it to stop once it has hit a wall then? I assumed while would be the most logical way. EDIT: and by stop, I mean make it so I have to click "start" again before it will register a wall hit.

Comment: it should be x == 1 or x === 1 not x = 1

Comment: I'm aware, although that still crashes it.

Comment: The `while` loop is going to execute an infinite number of times whether it's `x=1` or `x==1` because the value of `x` never changes in the loop.

Comment: This should stop mouseenter and mouseleave:
$('#myTable tr td.finish').unbind("mouseenter");
$('#myTable tr td.finish').unbind("mouseenter");
$('#myTable tr td.wall').unbind("mouseleave");

Comment: @brouxhaha since the statement immediately follows the initialization of "x" to `1`, what would be the point?

Comment: @juvian That looks like it may solve my issue, but how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: Guess @scott has already made a great example, good luck with your game!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the `while` loop is no real help here.  And as you keep rebinding event handlers inside it, it's causing your issues.  You can see one approach that works in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/bM8g4/)**.  All it does it tracks the same thing you were trying to do with `x` with a variable named `working`, setting and unsetting it based on when you start, finish, or run into walls.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var working = false;
    $('.start').click(function() {
        working = true;
    });
    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseenter',function(){
        if (working) {
            $('body').css( "background-color", "yellow");
            alert("You hit a wall!");
        }
        working = false;
    });
    $('#myTable tr td.finish').on('mouseenter',function(){
        if (working) {
            alert("You did it!");
        }
        working = false;
    });
    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $('body').css( "background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  But can I suggest that if you approve one of our answers it should be the one from sabof, who had almost identical code, and beat me to it (by a matter of seconds, it's true, but still!)

Comment: Doesn't matter. You've covered the finishing case which I didn't

Comment: I read both, the reason I marked yours as correct is due to the explanation. I did however upvote @sabof 's answer as it was correct as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it. It's easier than manipulating event bindings.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var isRunning = false;

  $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseenter',function(){
    if (isRunning) {
      $('body').css( "background-color", "yellow");
      alert("You hit a wall!");
      isRunning = false;
    }    
  })

  $('#myTable tr td.finish').on('mouseenter',function(){
    if (isRunning)
      alert("You did it!");
  })

  $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('body').css( "background-color", "white");
  })

  $('.start').click(function() {
    isRunning = true;
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/UA6Kg/

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds!  :-)  Same solution, different variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 while(x=1)
```

Use :

```
 while(x==1)
```

Comment: And this will not help at all because "x" is never changed in the loop.

Comment: I'm aware, although that still crashes it. Someone else has said the same thing.

Comment: @Pointy I have x=x+1 in the loop.

Comment: @MathewMacLean no you don't. You have `x = x + 1` **inside the event handlers**, and they won't run until an event actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need a `while` loop to check if the player has lost or won.  You can simply set the `mouseenter` events of the walls and the finish line to call a certain function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    walls =  $('#myTable tr td.wall');
    finish = $('#myTable tr td.finish');

    walls.on('mouseenter', playerLost);
    finish.on('mouseenter', playerWon);   
}

function playerLost() {
   // Your "player has lost" code here
}

function playerWon() {
   // Your "player has won" code here
}
```

You could also add the `walls`'s `mouseleave` event in the same way.

Comment: This looks like almost exactly what I'm looking for! How would I incorporate the $('.start').click(function() part though?

Comment: Put the code on my `document.ready` function in a new function (called 'setup', for example), and then set the start button's click event to that function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your while loop from this:

```
while(x=1)
```

to this:

```
while(x === 1)
```

This way you are using the [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators) to see if the **x** value is 1

Comment: This will not help at all, though it's true that the `while` statement is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is an infinite loop which freezes the javascript engine in the browser.  Instead of checking the state of your world in an infinite loop, you can use `setTimeout` which calls a `nextStep` function periodically, e.g. every 250 milliseconds:

```
var x = 1;

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.start').click(function() {
        nextStep();
    })
});

function nextStep() {
        if (x == 1) {

            $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseenter',function(){
                $('body').css( "background-color", "yellow");
                x=x+1;
                alert("You hit a wall!");
            })
            $('#myTable tr td.finish').on('mouseenter',function(){
                x=x+1;
                alert("You did it!");
            })
            $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseleave',function(){
                $('body').css( "background-color", "white");
            })

            setTimeout(nextStep, 250);
        }
    });
}
```

Which you can see working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V2wxT/7/).

Also, it's important to use the equality operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=` in your while condition.

Comment: I don't see how this helps.  Does it actually work for you?  That is, for instance, does it alert the message when you hit a wall after clicking start?

Comment: it was working for me but something happened to the fiddle.  Your answer is better.  I was trying to eliminate the infinite loop quickly without assessing the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you can do so

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('.start').click(on);
});

function on(){ 
     $('body').css( "background-color", "white");

    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $('body').css( "background-color", "yellow");

        alert("You hit a wall!");

                 off();
    });
    $('#myTable tr td.finish').on('mouseenter',function(){
        alert("You did it!");

                    off();
    });
    $('#myTable tr td.wall').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $('body').css( "background-color", "white");
    });
}

function off(){
    $('#myTable tr td.wall').off();
    $('#myTable tr td.finish').off();
    $('#myTable tr td.wall').off();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V2wxT/8/